# Modify the server side functions using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing one website using cakephp and jquery technologies.

Server-side there are some functions which handles SQL queries.

As per requirement I want to modify server side functions on client side using jQuery AJAX call.

**E.g.** : Below is the function on server side to modify users information.

```
function modifyUser(username,userid) {
  //update query statements
}
```

Then jquery AJAX call will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'users/modiyUser',
  success: function() {
    alert("Updation done") or any statements.
  }
});
```

and I want to modify above i.e. server side function depending upon client input criteria.

```
$.ajax({
 function users/modiyUser(username,userid) {
    // I will write here any other statements which gives me some other output.
 }
});
```

Above AJAX call syntax may not present, but i think you all understood what I am trying to do I simply wants to modify/override server side functions on client side.

Please let me know is there any way to resolve above mentioned requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either I didn't understand your requirement or your requirement is quite strange: you want to modify server side functions from client side which obviously is not possible.

Comment: You should also watch out for modifying stuff with AJAX, it could be exploited if done wrong!

Comment: As henrikh says: don't go there.  Security!!! You are putting server-side code into your webpages unprotected for all the world to see so anybody can modify it and then submit the results.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a PHP functions from the client directly. You can only make an HTTP request to a URI.

The URI determines the PHP script run. Input can be taken via `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` (among others, but those are the main ones).

You can either write separate scripts for each function or determine what to do based on the user input.

Comment: Thanks folks for your quick reply

@Darin : Yes you are right here my requirement is bit strange.

@David : Yes we can use get,post and etc.

I know this is strange requirement, Is there a way to dynamically generate functions which will give me server database access so that i can directly write separate functions.
As you mentioned server side function can not modify from client side, But can i write separate function which give me some result.

Comment: If you put enough effort into it, it is possible to upload PHP-code to the server and execute it. This is a huge security risk. Please don't do it. Just keep your server-side code on the server only. Just like everybody else does.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a server-side function in a separate PHP file to do this, and make an AJAX call call into that function first to perform the modification. But client-side changes to server-side code are just not possible.

I can't actually imagine why you would want to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

why override a function???

can i suggest this?

in **PHP**

```
try {
  // functions here....
  function modifyUser($username,$userid) {
     //update query statements
     if(!is_string($username)) throw new Exception("argument to " . __METHOD__ . " must be a string");
     if(!is_string($userid)) throw new Exception("argument to " . __METHOD__ . " must be a string");
     // do some modification codes....
  }
  function delete($userid){
      // do stuff blah blahh...
  }

  // $_POST or $_GET etc. here
  if(isset($_GET["modify"])){ // I make use of get for simplicity sake...
     $username = $_GET['username'];
     $userid = $_GET['userid'];
     modifyUser($username,$userid);
     $ret = array();
     $ret["error"] = false;
     $ret["msg"] = "$username has been modified";
     echo json_encode($ret);
  } else if(isset($_GET["delete"])) {
     $userid = $_GET['userid'];
     delete($userid);
     $ret = array();
     $ret["error"] = false;
     $ret["msg"] = "$username has been deleted";
     echo json_encode($ret);
  }else {
 // the client asked for something we don't support
 throw new Exception("not supported operation");
  }

}
catch(Exception $e){
    // something bad happened
    $ret = array();
    $ret["error"] = true;
    $ret["msg"] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
```

in **jQuery** ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data : { modify : true, // sample for modify... can also be delete : true,
        username : $('#username').val(),
        userid : $('#userid').val() },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
        alert('error in connection');
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(data.error)
            alert('Something went wrong: ' + data.msg);
        else {
            alert('Success: ' + data.msg);
        }    

    }
});
```